# Matlab's MultiStart runs fine, but GlobalSearch bugs out

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to run a global optimization in Matlab using the global optimization toolbox.  I am using the `fmincon` local optimizer as an input.  I am able to successfully run the `fmincon` local optimizer, as well as the `MultiStart` global optimizer with this problem.  However, when I try to set it up as a `GlobalSearch`, I get an error message.

Below is the code I am trying to use for the `GlobalSearch`:

```
%the functions is f(w) rather than f(x)

%constraints:
A = [1,0,0; 0,1,0; 0,0,1];
b = [.80, .80, .80];
Aeq = [1 1 1];
beq = 1;
lb = .10 * [1 1 1];
ub = .8 * [1 1 1];

w = [weight1, weight2, weight3];     
wstart = randn(3,1);

options = optimset('Algorithm','interior-point');

% function handle for the objective function (note that variables 
% aa through hh are additional parameters that the solver does not modify): 
h = @(w)Difference_in_Returns(w(1),w(2),w(3), aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh);

% problem structure:
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','x0',wstart,'objective',h,'Aineq',A,...'
'bineq',b,'Aeq',Aeq,'beq',beq,'options',options,'lb',lb,'ub',ub);

gs = GlobalSearch;
run(gs,problem)
```

When I try to run this, Matlab bugs out and prints:

```
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\globaloptim\globaloptim\private\
globalsearchnlp.p>i_calcConstrViolation (line 593)

Error in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\globaloptim\globaloptim\private\
globalsearchnlp.p>i_calcPenalty (line 627)

Error in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\globaloptim\globaloptim\private\
globalsearchnlp.p>globalsearchnlp (line 343)

Error in GlobalSearch/run (line 330)
        [x,fval,exitflag,output] = ...
Error in Optimization_Setup (line 62)
run(gs,problem)
```

I believe the problem is outlined by the lines:

```
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in GlobalSearch/run (line 330)
        [x,fval,exitflag,output] = ...
```

Any tips are highly appreciated.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Two thoughts. Does it change anything if you return outputs: `[x,f]=run(gs,problem)`? And, your variable `wstart` is a column vector -what if you transpose it (some functions handle both gracefully, others not)?

Comment: @horchler: Thank you for your quick response!  I tried adding `[x,f]=run(gs,problem)` but the error persists.  I tried transposing the `wstart` variable, but that did not fix the error either.

Comment: Can you give us 'Difference_in_Returns' ? If it's a complicated function, can you give us a minimal example that reproduces the error?

Comment: @Sevenless: 'Difference_in_Return' is a very complex function that relies on a large amount of data; it would be hard for me to provide it.  It seems that no matter what I use for `wstart` I get the error.